# C# app to call Python script that uses USB-to-CAN transceiver

Tags: c#, python, can-bus

Just wondering if someone out there might have some insight to what's going wrong here...

I have a python script that connects to a USB-to-CAN transceiver/dongle (made by PEAK System) to do some CAN communications. The script works pretty flawlessly. The script accepts command-line arguments and works fine when called from the Windows command-line.

I am trying to integrate this script into a C# Forms project. I have been successful at calling the Python script from the C# app, but things fall apart when it gets to the point at which the Python script tries to use the CAN transceiver.

It feels like the C# app front-end is not allowing the Python script to access the serial port.

Here is the error I get (Python script writing to StandardOut on the Visual Studio output):

```
line 86, in canSendRec    
   self.bus.send(canMessage, timeout=0.1)    
AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'bus'    
Unable to Connect to USB-CAN Device
```

Here is the line from canSendRec -- where the exception handler came from (which we wrote):

```
try:
    self.bus = can.interface.Bus('PCAN_USBBUS1',bitrate=1000000)
    self.bus.flush_tx_buffer()
except:
    print("Unable to Connect to USB-CAN Device")
```

Here is my C# code calling the Python script:

```
    public string pythonMakeCall(string script, string arg1){
        ProcessStartInfo pyProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(py_path);
        pyProcessStartInfo.FileName = py_path;
        pyProcessStartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", script, arg1);  
        pyProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        pyProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        pyProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        pyProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        Process pyProcess = new Process();
        pyProcess.StartInfo = pyProcessStartInfo;
        pyProcess.Start();

        retString = pyProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        pyProcess.WaitForExit();
        return retString;}
```

Like I said, it feels like there is something going on with the C# app not allowing Python to access the USB ports, but I'm not sure where to begin with debugging that hunch, since, **Disclaimer:** this is my first time dabbling in C#/Visual Studio and I'm no Python expert either.

Comment: That's not enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Pretty sure I would have to give you the entire project to reproduce the issue, which I'm not going to do. 

**Just was wondering** if someone had insight into allowing a Python script to access the USB port when the Python script is called from a C# app.